# Map function error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import endoskopi from '../Images/endoskopi.jpg';
import '../Css/diagnosis.css'
import {Route,Switch,BrowserRouter,Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import ChosenDiagnosis from "./ChosenDiagnosis";
import App from "./App";


class Diagnosis extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


static propTypes = {
    diagnosis: PropTypes.array
};


render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/diagnosis' component={App}/>
                    <Route path='/diagnosis/:id' component={ChosenDiagnosis}/>
                </Switch>

                <div className="row">
                    {( this.props.diagnosis || [] ).map(diagnosis =>{
                        return (<div key={diagnosis.id} className="col-md-4" style={{marginTop:"2rem"}}>
                            <div className="diagnosis-box">
                                <img className="diagnosis-img" src={endoskopi} alt={diagnosis.name}/>
                                <div className="diagnosis-text">{diagnosis.name}</div>
                                <Link to={`/diagnosis/${diagnosis.id}`}>
                                    <button className={"diagnosis-button"}>Ücreti Sorgula</button>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>)
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}

export default Diagnosis;
```

Hello , I am a newbie at **Reactjs**. I got this error but I do not understand the reason because my '**diagnosis**' array has been declared in **app.js** . Also, I put '**Switch**' block to under the all codes but it did not work. May you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

state={
  diagnosis: [
      {
          name: "EKG",
          id: 1
      },
      {
          name: "Ultrason",
          id: 2
      },
      {
          name: "MR",
          id: 3
      },
      {
          name: "Röntgen",
          id: 4
      },
      {
          name: "EEG",
          id: 5
      },
      {
          name: "EMG",
          id: 6
      },
      {
          name: "Kan Testi",
          id: 7
      },
      {
          name: "İdrar Testi",
          id: 8
      },
      {
          name: "Tomografi",
          id: 9
      },
      {
          name: "Endoskopi",
          id: 10
      },
  ]
};


render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar/>
    <Diagnosis diagnosis={this.state.diagnosis}/>
  </div>
);
```

}
    }

```
export default App;
```

It's also my another component which is App.js. (Edited by request)

Comment: try: `{this.props.diagnosis && this.props.diagnosis.map(diagnosis => {`  but, `this.props` is object of Your current component not the app. seem like You've to "inject" that property when You call it somewhere like: `<DiagnosisOrWhatEverComponent diagnosis={this.state.diagnosis} />`

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer. I have already wright <DiagnosisOrWhatEverComponent diagnosis={this.state.diagnosis} /> in app.js and I have created another component. All of these codes are written in the another component. By the way I tried that {this.props.diagnosis && this.props.diagnosis.map(diagnosis =>  but my app is stopped. I do not have any idea about the reason:)

Comment: Crashed or just not rendering the listing?

Comment: Also, can we see other components?

Comment: When I click any button on my app , it is waitin and I can not click anything else. When 'I delete this.props.diagnosis &&' it works again before I tried it. I do not take any error but it is not working as well. It is like frost.. (I have edited my post and added another component :) )

Comment: add other components

Comment: I have added app.js component as well. thank you for your consideration btw.

Comment: Actually, it works with this static data but probably your routing is not right as its current state. What is your intention here? How is your whole App structure?

Comment: Firstly , I am trying to show some photos which have buttons. When user click the buttons of any photo, it will show only this photo and some information about the photo. Every photo has unique id and when user click the button , route catches the id and works..

Comment: add to Diagnosis: `onComponentDidMount() { console.log('Diagnosis: ', this.props); }`  and see what's in inspector panel (console tab)

Comment: I also suspect that `state.diagnosis` is undefined in `App` class and when it's being pushed it's not iterable. seems like state gets changed somehow

Comment: @devserkan btw I think he has overloaded constructor of Diagnosis class like he did with App and forgot to pass props :D. Cause he don't share with us overall Diagnosis component. So we're just guessing why it's not working with static data

Comment: Might be, since we don't see the rest of `Diagnosis` component here. @ÇağataySert, can we see it if possible?

Comment: I have edited my post again :)  I added all parts of my component.

Comment: App renders Diagnosis, Diagnosis renders App :O

Comment: you've got cyclic dependencies (probably App is `undefined`)

Comment: OP has just changed the code. `/diagnosis` was rendering `Diagnosis` component at first :) And this is why when it hits `/diagnosis` props is undefined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this static data, your code should work actually. You don't have to use any conditional rendering here. But the error in your question indicates that when your component renders the first time there isn't any `diagnosis` prop at that time. We should examine this.

One other problem is in your route definition. Probably you want to do something like that:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/diagnosis' component={Diagnosis}/>
    <Route path='/diagnosis/:id' component={ChosenDiagnosis}/>
</Switch>
```

Look this part: `path='/diagnosis/:id'`.

To guarantee let's try this in your code with the fix above:

```
{( this.props.diagnosis || [] ).map(diagnosis => { ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. When I click any button , my app crushes and I do not take any error. Probably , I made mistake which is related routing because without changing route, map function and app is working.

Comment: You are welcome. By saying "changing route" you mean fixing it like I did or going another path? Can you put your app to codesandbox.io or you can update your question again with the whole app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried ur codes and now it works.. :)

Comment: You are welcome again but still, this solution might be problematic. I still don't understand the app structure very well but `/diagnosis` path might be the problem here. It might cause a loop. So, try to examine React Router a little bit :)

Comment: Okay , I will give attention to your suggestion. :))

Answer (score 0):

try to change this part:

```
           <Switch>
                <Route path='/diagnosis' component={Diagnosis}/>
                <Route path='/diagnosis:id' component={ChosenDiagnosis}/>
            </Switch>
```

to:

```
           <Switch>
                <Route path='/diagnosis' render={() => <Diagnosis diagnosis={this.props.diagnosis}/>}/>
                <Route path='/diagnosis:id' component={ChosenDiagnosis}/>
            </Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer : ) I got an error about the last '}' when I change my code.